# Training Questions Considered Harmful

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Do you think at any point that the review Q might actually decide that I know what I'm doing and I'm not going to just randomly hit close or skip or It looks ok.

When I opened the review Low Quality posts today I got to review an answer to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8428949

(the answer I reviews seems to have been deleted now)

The question has been deleted, (which it said in the review Q - so if I had been trying to beat the 'You're not paying attention' automated police I would have know it was a test - like the random tag added to random question test questions in the close Q).

I thought the answer (which suggested to this OP that they use the Import tools built in to Outlook to fix his issue.  It wasn't an amazing answer, but it was good and polite and tried to answer the question.

I got the "Stop and Look you Fool" note, which told me I had said that I had allowed an obnoxious answer to be passed and I should watch out for this kind of thing in the future.

The Question was awful and had been deleted, the answer in my opinion actually was fine.

Now after that rant, maybe I could make a few suggestions.

1. Do reviewers with > 1000 reviews on Q's still need to get these silly notifications?
2. Please don't use deleted Questions or Answers for the test questions.
3. I now keep on the lookout for these silly questions so I can beat the game rather than get the nasty dialog.
4. This may not happen anymore, but don't simply add the tag I'm reviewing to a random bad Q or A. E.g. just add my PHP tag to a c++ question.  This really gives the review away.

Comment: for bullet 1 the answer is yes. bullet 4: That is the whole point of the audit, they couldn't be missed and even with that knowledge you failed! (don't take it to hard, I fail a review sometimes as well although I have not done so many reviews)

Comment: Audits don't care if you skip; that's always a valid action. (It won't *pass* the audit, but it won't fail either.) That's by design, since "randomly" skipping through reviews won't do any real harm either.

Answer (score 5):

I think these silly notifications are necessary. I have 1000+ reviews on all queues and know that the knowledge of encountering a review audit keeps my concentration level up, and missing one has been a flag to stop reviewing and go to bed (late at night), or first wake up and get enough coffee in my system (in the morning).

What is unfortunate is that, instead of fully giving attention to the post under review,  I start to look at things like "is the date that this question was posted a give-away that it might be an audit".

I do however see that separate from getting good and fair review audits and having some mechanism to flag the audits (which are automatically selected) and have the counter for missed audits adjusted if the flag is honoured.

I don't mind being kept on my toes. But it has to be possible to complain if things seem unfair. It would also help to know what exactly the consequences are. Currently I think that you get blocked for a day or two on the second failed audit, but it is unclear:

- if the first one expires after X days
- if the failed audits have to be on the same queue
- what your current fail status is

It's like the points against your driving license you get in some countries for offences. It would be kind of unfair if they never expire nor if you cannot easily find out what your status is.

AFAIK the Help and Improvement queue has no audits yet (at least I have not encountered any), so feel welcome to help clear that queue.

Comment: I've failed lots of audits, but have never been review-banned, so they either expire or take the proportion of intervening successes into account. (Probably the latter.)